# PHP merge array by "depth"?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "function_1": {
            "element": {
                "error": "0",
                "msg": "test"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "function_1": {
            "element_2": {
                "error": "0",
                "msg": "test"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "function_2": {
            "element": {
                "error": "0",
                "msg": "test"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "function_2": {
            "element_2": {
                "error": "0",
                "msg": "test"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I want output like this:

```
[
    {
        "function_1": {
            "element": {
                "error": "0",
                "msg": "test"
            },
            "element_2": {
                "error": "0",
                "msg": "test"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "function_2": {
            "element": {
                "error": "0",
                "msg": "test"
            },
            "element_2": {
                "error": "0",
                "msg": "test"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The answers that I found offered to search by name("function_1", "function_2"). But this does not suit me, the function will not always pass an array. I need exactly the "depth" or any other reasonable way.
Thank you!

Comment: the added array data isn't valid ?

Comment: @OMiShah What do you mean?

Comment: the data format is incorrect. Is this JSON array output from some API?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired result, you could json-decode, recursively merge each individual subarray, then loop over that structure to push each item as a second-level array like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DTH7j))

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$merged = array_merge_recursive(...$array);

$result = [];
foreach ($merged as $key => $data) {
    $result[] = [$key => $data];
}
var_export($result);
```

---

But I can't imagine getting any benefit from adding unnecessary depth to your result array.  I recommend simply json decoding, then calling `array_merge_recursive()` with the spread operator: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nCSCG))

```
var_export(
    array_merge_recursive(
        ...json_decode($json, true)
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'function_1' => 
  array (
    'element' => 
    array (
      'error' => '0',
      'msg' => 'test',
    ),
    'element_2' => 
    array (
      'error' => '0',
      'msg' => 'test',
    ),
  ),
  'function_2' => 
  array (
    'element' => 
    array (
      'error' => '0',
      'msg' => 'test',
    ),
    'element_2' => 
    array (
      'error' => '0',
      'msg' => 'test',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: To clear up any suspected hammer abuse: I did not find this duplicate until 5 days after answering.  If I delete my answer now, then only suboptimal answers will be presented here.  I'll leave this answer as viewable for researcher benefit.  I support the removal of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure looks weird for the purpose you are trying to achieve I'm bored af tho and created this code for you

```
function combineElementsPerfunction($functions) {

   $result = [];

    $uniqueFunctions = [];
    foreach ($functions as $function) {
        $functionName = array_keys($function)[0];
        $uniqueFunctions[] = $functionName;
    }
    $uniqueFunctions = array_unique($uniqueFunctions);
    foreach ($uniqueFunctions as $uniqueFunction) {
        $functionObjects = array_filter(
            $functions,
            function($function) use ($uniqueFunction) {
                $functionName = array_keys($function)[0];
                return $functionName === $uniqueFunction;
            }
        );
        
        $elements = [];
        foreach ($functionObjects as $functionObject) {
            $function = array_shift($functionObject);
            $elements = array_merge($elements, $function);
        }
        
        $result[] = [
            $uniqueFunction => $elements
        ];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The amount of your code scares me. Can't this just be solved with a single foreach loop?

Comment: @Humster, and your expected output scares us!

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation, I hope your boredom is sufficient to improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeArr($data){
    $box = $new = [];
    foreach ($data as $v){
        $key = array_key_first($v);
        $i = count($box);
        if(in_array($key, $box)){
            $keys = array_flip($box);
            $i = $keys[$key];
        }else{
            $box[] = $key;
        }
        $new[$i][$key] = isset($new[$i][$key]) ? array_merge($new[$i][$key], $v[$key]) : $v[$key];
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.